# Batch file to clean Unity directory of junk files

Tags: unity-game-engine

Unity creates a bunch of junk binary files. From what I understand a lot of those files are temporary and are unnecessary. Is there a batch script already written which can delete these files? If not, which files are safe to delete and which files are critical to the integrity of the scene files?

Comment: Not really a Perforce question.

Comment: We are using perforce that's why its under that category.

Comment: Well yes I assumed that you are using Perforce, however as your question asked nothing specific to do *with* I removed the tag/category so that you will most likely get a better answer (e.g. what files in a Unity compile are temporary?).

Comment: The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity. Please don't misuse it.

Answer (score 4):

This is here for anyone who wants now working batch file.
Unity produces a lot of junk files within your save, and I strongly suggest you run this script every time you save a backup of your project.

Instructions:
Copy and paste code into batch file.
put batch file inside your unity project file
run the file, read instructions, press enter a few times, wait, and all done! you just saved 30-50 mb of disk space!

```
@echo off
echo %cd%
echo "this will delete some files within the directory above!  Make sure unity is not running!"
pause
echo "are you sure you would like to do this?"
pause
rd /s /q Library
rd /s /q Temp
del /s /q /f *.csproj
del /s /q /f *.pidb
del /s /q /f *.unityproj
del /s /q /f *.DS_Store
del /s /q /f *.sln
del /s /q /f *.userprefs
echo "done."
pause
```

Answer (score 2):

You can ignore these file extensions for unity

```
*.csproj
*.pidb
*.unityproj
*.DS_Store
*.sln
*.userprefs
```

and anything under

```
<PATH TO PROJECT>/Library/*
<PATH TO PROJECT>/Temp/*
```

just make sure they dont conflict with non unity projects ;)

Keep your meta files if your using it for Version control.

Instead of making a batch file to delete them if you just dont want other Perforce users in your group to get them simply add these sorts of lines to your workspace (swapping out the paths and CLIENT for the right one)

```
-//depot/foo/*.csproj //CLIENT/foo/*.csproj
-//depot/foo/.../*.pidb //CLIENT/foo/.../*.pidb
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to clean up files by file extension (say all `.tmp` files in a directory strucutre) you can achieve this with `find` on osx and linux.

e.g.

```
find . -name "*.tmp" -exec rm {} \;
```

If you know the extensions (or names) of the files that are temporarly generated you can remove them in this way.